# spotify play song without login using API on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I want to develop application where i can listen songs from spotify without login into it.like we search from soundcloud and play it.

i had implemented API for searching tracks

> https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Muse&type=track,artist&market=US

it provides me list of tracks now how can i play it without login.

the response is look likw below

```
{
external_urls: {
spotify: "https://open.spotify.com/artist/12Chz98pHFMPJEknJQMWvI"
},
followers: {
href: null,
total: 1856949
},
genres: [ ],
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/12Chz98pHFMPJEknJQMWvI",
id: "12Chz98pHFMPJEknJQMWvI",
images: [
{
height: 667,
url: "https://i.scdn.co/image/0b3c04473aa6a2db8235e5092ec3413f35752b8d",
width: 1000
},
{
height: 427,
url: "https://i.scdn.co/image/cf54c2d4a4549fb484862a9c475fc897bb5ce707",
width: 640
},
{
height: 133,
url: "https://i.scdn.co/image/837c977024362a7f6d1873027e2a8664e21f911a",
width: 200
},
{
height: 43,
url: "https://i.scdn.co/image/0b14ff7b9c9fcfaf6b662fe439576c531b0aa8d8",
width: 64
}
],
name: "Muse",
popularity: 81,
type: "artist",
uri: "spotify:artist:12Chz98pHFMPJEknJQMWvI"
},
```

Comment: Yes, Thank ´s Eric D for his point... Like he said... There ist no music url... in your JSON... Just images... Thanks Eric

Comment: @Neo You're welcome. Actually I think OP has to use the Spotify SDK with auth keys to listen to tracks, but I couldn't find a reference for this. Maybe it's possible to listen to the free ones without the SDK but it won't work anyway with just these links from OP's response.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a Spotify player this summer, and indeed you have to use their SDK (https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk).

Without logging in you can only play the **30 second previews** of the songs, only when you are logged in you can play the full songs. The previews can (have to) be played with the iOS audio classes, the full songs when logged in have to be played with the SDK's own player.

Comment: I wish this was written in swift!

Comment: This is using Obj-c and in beta version

Comment: Plus this is your only chance :-).

Comment: It's in beta for almost a year, they do it so they don't have to give support or any warranty imho.

Comment: How can i play 30 second previews ? @TheEye

Comment: They are part of the song info you get when you request the songs from the API (at least when you use the framework). Those calls do not need a log in to Spotify. The preview URLs can be played with the iOS audio player classes.